# Equivalent of /? for cmd commands in powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

To get help about a command in Windows Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`, I can do:

```
rmdir /?
xcopy /?
etc.
```

How do I do that in PowerShell?

Comment: A shortcut (although may not be implemented for all commands) is using `-?`.  This will access the help document like doing `Get-Help -Name Get-Command`

Comment: How did you not google "command help powershell" and find something like https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-powershell-cookbook/9780596528492/ch01s06.html ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answer is `Get-Help`.

It shows `Syntax`,`Aliases`,`Examples` and a lot more.

Example:
`Get-Help rmdir`

```
NAME
    Remove-Item

SYNTAX
    Remove-Item [-Path] <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-Recurse] [-Force]
    [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction] [-Stream <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Remove-Item -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-Recurse]
    [-Force] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction] [-Stream <string[]>]
    [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    ri
    rm
    rmdir
    del
    erase
    rd
```

For further info use the `-Full` or `-Detailed` parameter:
`Get-Help <command> -Detailed`:

```
NAME
    Remove-Item

SYNTAX
    Remove-Item [-Path] <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-Recurse]
    [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction] [-Stream <string[]>]  [<CommonParamet

    Remove-Item -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-Recu
    [-Force] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction] [-Stream <string[]>]
    [<CommonParameters>]


PARAMETERS
    -Confirm

    -Credential <pscredential>

    -Exclude <string[]>

    -Filter <string>

    -Force

    -Include <string[]>

    -LiteralPath <string[]>

    -Path <string[]>

    -Recurse

    -Stream <string[]>

    -UseTransaction

    -WhatIf

    <CommonParameters>
        This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
        ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
        OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see
        about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).


ALIASES
    ri
    rm
    rmdir
    del
    erase
    rd


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Remove-Item -Online" or
           go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373.
```

---

Commands like `xcopy` and `robocopy`, executeables on their own, often don't have a Powershell-Help-File.

To get informations about them, one can either try `/?` or `--?`.

Comment: @Gigi Thats right, very few commandlets do actually not have a help-file stored. Most of them are their own executeables and dont use Powershell-Help-Files. The only alternative to this is to hope that something like `--?` is implemented for the .exe . For example `xcopy --?` works as expected, so does `robocopy --?`.

Comment: @Gigi I also implemented this in the answer now.

Comment: true for rorbocopy; xcopy --? returns:
        File not found - --?
        0 File(s) copied

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-Help [command]
```

is the universal way of getting documentation for commands in PowerShell.